# Using dice as a kids game and summing random list of ints while excluding specific values from the final sum

Tags: python-3.x

The game begins with the player 'rolling 5 dice.' Then the player gets a score of the combined numbers of the dice excluding 2's and 5's. Any 2's or 5's rolled results in dice "stuck in the mud." So say you roll a [1, 3, 4, 5, 2] the score should be: 8. Then the player rolls the remaining 3 dice, again you rolled [6,3,2] the score should then be 17. So on and so forth until the player runs out of dice and the code returns a final score.

```
import random

print("One round of Stuck in the Mude")
game = input("Enter r to roll the dice or q to quit: ")

diceC = 5
while game == "r" and game != "q" and diceC > 0:

    dice = [random.randint(1,6) for i in range(diceC)]

    score = 0
    for d in dice:
        # the rules for getting a score
        if d==2 or d==5:
            diceC -= 1
            pass
        else:
            score = score + d

    print('dice rolls:', dice)
    print('score', score)
    game = input("Enter r to roll the dice or q to quit: ")
```

Comment: The indentation is completely broken.  Can you [edit] your post?

Comment: The best way to post and get the indentation correct is to select ALL of you code from wherever you have it, paste it in, and while it is selected, hit ctrl-k to format it.  Or re-select all of your code at once after it is in the window, and do same.

Comment: the code actually throws an error `ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list`,  what were you hoping to get ?

Comment: removing elements from a list changes the size of the list... is this what you want ?  it looks like you just want to count a score, so assign the values 5, 2 a score = 0....

Comment: @D.L I forgot to remove the value error in the code I posted. How would I assign 5, 2 the value of 0? I guess I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: question:  can you confirm that this game is being played with one dice and that it is the sum of the rolls apart from when the dice is a 2 or a 5 ?

Comment: @D.L yes the game is intended to roll 5 dice. The numbers rolled will be added to the score aside from 5 and 2. If a 5 and or 2 is rolled the dice displaying either value should be removed and players will roll the remaining dice until all 5 are "stuck in the mud." That is why I have the variable diceC = 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i add a new answer based on the comments to the last answer.

it appears that the OP requires this:

> when a 2 or 5 is rolled, the dice is removed from the game and the
> other dice continue to be rolled until there are no dice left.

We can reduce the dice list with a `list comprehension`.

This keeps playing the game until there are no dice left.

Here is the code:

```py
import random

score = 0
games_played = 0
number_rolls = 5

while True:
    games_played += 1
    if games_played > 100:
        print('more than 100 games played: you won !!!')
        break

    # user input:
    play_game = input("Enter r to roll the dice or q to quit: ")
    if play_game == 'q':
        break
    

    dice = [random.randint(1,6) for i in range(number_rolls)]
    print('dice rolled:', dice)
    dice = [d for d in dice if d in [1,3,4,6]]  # remove 2 & 5
    number_rolls = len(dice)
    
    if len(dice) == 0:
        break

    for d in dice:
        score = score + d
        print('current score:', score)
        

print('---end---')
print('games played:', games_played)
print('final score', score)
```

example result:

```
Enter r to roll the dice or q to quit: r
dice rolled: [6, 6, 6, 3, 2]
current score: 6
current score: 12
current score: 18
current score: 21
Enter r to roll the dice or q to quit: r
dice rolled: [3, 3, 4, 5]
current score: 24
current score: 27
current score: 31
Enter r to roll the dice or q to quit: r
dice rolled: [6, 5, 4]
current score: 37
current score: 41
Enter r to roll the dice or q to quit: r
dice rolled: [5, 5]
---end---
games played: 4
final score 41
```

Answer (score 0):

The attempt that you made was okay, but there was overuse of the lists (which probably confused you). In light of your comments, this would be a good clean solution to work from.

- need one variable for the number of rolls.
- only need one list (for the dice rolls).
- for loop over the list to generate the score.

(You never needed to append the lists, but in any event, one needs to be careful appending lists that they are iterating through as it risks going out of range).

Here is the code:

```py
import random

number_rolls = 5
dice = [random.randint(1,6) for i in range(number_rolls)]

score = 0
for d in dice:
    # the rules for getting a score
    if d==2 or d==5:
        pass
    else:
        score = score + d
        print('current score:', score)

print('---end---')
print('dice rolls:', dice)
print('final score', score)
```

result:

```
current score: 3
current score: 9
current score: 12
current score: 15
---end---
dice rolls: [3, 6, 3, 3, 5]
final score 15
```

Comment: the code you wrote is actually similar to a different attempt I wrote for this program which is comforting to me. Anyways this is really close to what I need but I'm not sure how to combine each score so after each roll the code returns a combined score including previous rolls.

Comment: @ak. there are two ways of doing this.  [1] change score to a list and append the list. [2] just add a `print` statement right under the score (i will append the answer for this).

Comment: I miscommunicated. Each time a player rolls they score. The player is going to roll until all 5 dice are no longer rollable. In your result the score is 15, but the player still has 4 dice to roll. The next produced score of x should be added to the previous score of 15 and so on and so forth until the player runs out of dice.

Comment: okay,  can you confirm this:  when a 2 or 5 is rolled, the dice is removed from the game and the other dice continue to be rolled until there are no dice left.  is that how you wanted to ask the question ?

Comment: yes but the game needs to run off user input. So the user has to input "r" for the dice to roll. Then in one return it should have... dice rolled: [x, x, x, x, x,] score: x        and then the loop should repeat "Enter r to roll the dice or q to quit: " from there the score of that roll should be counted on top of the previous roll while counting the number of dice a user has left

Comment: the first code you wrote was extremely close to what I want it to do. The only problem was that the score wasn't combining with the next roll.

Comment: @ak.  see the update in the new code...